# Deduction of no. of molecules crossing due to velocity gradient in mass flow

Tags: kinetic-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DACkx.jpg)

[image]

[image]

The above two pictures show the deduction of number of molecules crossing an imaginary plane for a mass flow of air molecules. Here we have considered horizontal direction to be the direction of mass flow . So due to velocity gradient there will be some motion perpendicular to mass flow and hence transfer of momentum. Now in the picture uploaded it's shown the deduction of number of particle crossing an intermediate plane. In this derivation for an elementary area $dA$ why do we integrate θ from 0 to $π/2$ and take it to be the required number as we miss the molecules on the other side( 0 to -π/2). Yes, we can't integrate from $-π/2 $to $π/2$ as the integral will become zero , but only 0 to π/2 it seems will miss some molecules from different directions. Please illuminate me on this deduction.

Comment: Below equation (2.21) they write that they compute the [...] "total number of molecules crossing $dA$ in time $dt$ from the $\textbf{half-space above xx'}$ and from all directions". Imo they do so to avoid the vanishing of the integral.

Comment: Yes, that I observed but why they say that this is the required equation as some molecules are excluded, that I am unable to understand.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the result for the lower half-space is excately the same as the one given above. It is just a matter of the reference system and by choosing the one they chose, the integral for $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ vanishes. That is why they compute it for one half-space only, so the end result is just double the result of one half-space.

Comment: @franz i was meaning the left side half space as when theta goes from 0 to π/2 it traverses the right space only, that's where I am confused. Thanks.